# Render entity field like checkboxes associated with their category in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a tags associated with categories by ManyToOne association. And I need to render all tags on template, but with one condition - they all should be devided by categories with with thay are linked. 
There should be something like this:

```
<label>Some category name</label>
   <input type="checkbox">Tag1
   <input type="checkbox">Tag2
   <input type="checkbox">Tag3

<label>Some different category name</label>
   <input type="checkbox">Tag1
   <input type="checkbox">Tag2
   <input type="checkbox">Tag3
```

..and so on.
Could anyone help me please)